# django view and templates are not integrated to urls.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

the url that I am trying to access is blog/2018/08 and blog/2018/08/14.
the other urls such as blog/, blog/2018, blog/today, archive/ works well
but urls containing month and day are not working.

this is my code:

blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import *

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostLV.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('post/', PostLV.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDV.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('archieve/', PostAV.as_view(), name='post_archive'),
    path('<int:year>/', PostYAV.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/', PostMAV.as_view(), name='post_month_archive'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/', PostDAV.as_view(), name='post_day_archive'),
    path('today/', PostTAV.as_view(), name='post_today_archive'),
           ]
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from  django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView, DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView

from blog.models import Post

# Create your views here.

class PostLV(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_all.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

class PostDV(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostAV(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive.html'

class PostYAV(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    make_object_list = True
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive_year.html'

class PostMAV(MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive_month.html'

class PostDAV(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive_day.html'

class PostTAV(TodayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive_today.html'
```

all the templates I got is mentioned in views.py!

thank you so much

Comment: What *exactly* happens when you try to access those URLs?

Comment: probably, you aren't appending slashes at the end of them. Just a guess.

Comment: You're getting 404 or 'TemplateDoesNotExist'? or what?

Comment: @DanielRoseman omg i forgot to write the error ... Im getting Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2018/08/
Raised by: blog.views.PostMAV
Invalid date string '2018__8__' given format '%Y__%b__'

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the month format. Date views default to using abbreviated string format for dates - in English, "jan", "feb" etc. But you're using integers, so you need to tell the view that:

```
class PostMAV(MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    template_name = 'blog/post_archive_month.html'
    month_format = '%m'
```